# Upgraded to 22.10 and can no longer scale resolution on my 3 x 32" monitors

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 22.10

I just updated to 21.10 and now cannot scale any of my 3 32" monitors.

Everything has worked fine with Ubuntu 18 to 22.04 with no issues.

Now I get a message that says:

"Changes cannot be applied, this could be due to hardware limitations".

If I switch to Wayland I can scale 2 of my monitors and not the 3rd.

Currently 2 are display ports and one is HDMI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this issue after upgrading ubuntu 22.10.

Disable all monitors other than your primary display.

Set the scale you wish to have.

Enable the remaining monitors and scale them as well.